# How to run same pakcage twice at the same time?

Tags: ros, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
im currently running the sicktoolbox_wrapper package for the LMS200 for scanning purpose
I have two LMS200 and would like to use them at the same time
I know the connecting port which are ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1

lets say im running in port ttyUSB0
when i execute the command of

rosparam set /sicklms/port /dev/ttyUSB1
rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms

the old one is killed because of

> [new node registered with the same
> name]

is there any possible way to change the node name before executing it?
or is it possible to copy and paste then reinstall the same package with a different and publishing a different node name?

I am trying rosparam set but have not found a clue yet
plx help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151971/how-to-run-same-pakcage-twice-at-the-same-time?/) by [fcl21](https://answers.ros.org/users/14726/fcl21/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/31944/rosrun-node_name/), it shows how to set the node name both from the command line and from launch files.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fcl21](https://answers.ros.org/users/14726/fcl21/) on 2014-04-11**:
let me make it clear
if i execute
rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms __name:=sicklms
it is executable but doesnt change anything

if i execute this
rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms __name:=sicklms2
i have
[ERROR] [1397226096.240203952]: Initialize failed! are you using the correct device path?
:/

**Comment by [fcl21](https://answers.ros.org/users/14726/fcl21/) on 2014-04-11**:
i just found that if i do

rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms __name:=sicklms2

it says
attempting to open devic @ /dev/lms200
which is a path that i never told the computer to do

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-11**:
This is probably the default value. You will need to set the parameter `rosparam set /sicklms2/port /dev/ttyUSB1` when you run `rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms __name:=sicklms2`. It is probably best if you create a launch file for your nodes.